# Open /var/log/syslog and reading data using poll(), but poll() always reading same data again

Tags: linux, system-calls, epoll

Test Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 
Description: I did the below

```
# `sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog`
# logger "helloworld".
# `cat /var/log/syslog/`

May 21 11:02:10 setup-VirtualBox setup: `helloworld`

May 21 11:05:01 setup-VirtualBox CRON[3056]: `(root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`
```

But if am reading data through below program am repeatedly getting the two lines.

what is the problem ?

```
data:May 21 11:02:10 setup-VirtualBox setup: `helloworld`
May 21 11:05:01 setup-VirtualBox CRON[3056]: `(root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`

data:May 21 11:02:10 setup-VirtualBox setup: `helloworld`
May 21 11:05:01 setup-VirtualBox CRON[3056]: `(root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`

data:May 21 11:02:10 setup-VirtualBox setup: `helloworld`
May 21 11:05:01 setup-VirtualBox CRON[3056]: `(root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`
```

The code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/poll.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    int main()
    {
        int fd = open("/var/log/syslog", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd  == -1)
        {
            perror("open");
            return 0;
        }

        int ret = 0;
        struct pollfd p;
        p.fd = fd;
        p.events = POLLIN;
        char dataBuff[1000];
        memset(dataBuff, 0, 1000);
        int i = 0;
        int numEvents = 0;
        /* wait for events */
        while (1) 
        {
            numEvents = poll(&p, 1, -1);
            if (numEvents > 0) 
            {
                if (0 != (POLLIN & p.revents))
                {
                    ret = read(p.fd, dataBuff,1000);
                    if (ret > 0)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "data:%s\n",dataBuff);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: `poll()` doesn't work on normal files. (Or rather, it *works* but doesn't do anything useful.)

Longer version: the `POLLIN` event simply means that, if you call `read()` on the file descriptor, it will not block. However, this is always true for normal files: if you are at the end of the file, then `read()` will return 0 immediately. You are seeing the same data here repeatedly because you are failing to add a terminating null byte to `dataBuff` each time around your loop. In reality, `read()` is not reading any data beyond the first time.

To block until a file is modified, you will need to use the Linux-specific `inotify()` API. Alternatively, if you do not need to be notified immediately when new data appears, you can simply attempt a read periodically (e.g, once every second) and see if new data is available.

---

As a last note, a warning: not all file systems support `inotify()`. In particular, VirtualBox shared folders do not support notifications. (I mention this here because it looks like you're using VirtualBox. It doesn't affect this *specific* use case, as `/var/log` is not in a shared folder, but it's something to be aware of.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added terminating NULL here. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is.
Just one addition add memset(dataBuff, 0, 1000); before read

Comment: It "works" with that change, but clearly not in the way that was intended. (For the reasons explained in my answer, `poll()` is not returning useful data.)

Comment: I verified what you said @duskwuff.  yes u r right. POLLIN in always true in normal file case. So i need to go for inotify. Nice input. Thanks for the info.